# Fluidsynth - How to modulate/manipulate audio from separate midi channels

Tags: c, signal-processing, synthesizer, fluidsynth

I am using the `fluid_synth_process ()` function in my custom fx function to modulate audio according to  [the example in](http://www.fluidsynth.org/api/fluidsynth_fx_8c-example.html). But this seems to modulate audio from all midi channels globally. How do I modulate audio output from every midi channel separately?